# Smoothly extend eased animation to new target value

Tags: c++, animation

I am implementing animated `double` property from scratch, currently with SmoothStep easing, however when new target value is set, there is visible "jump" in animation speed (probably due to applied easing). I would like `setTarget` to smoothly extend currently ongoing animation. 
I have tried to calculate `originalValue_` and `remaining_` based on current `t` (offsetting those correctly, I think, will solve the problem), but haven't managed to find the correct formula. 
How do I smoothly extend ongoing smoothstep animation to new target value?

```
void setTargetValue(double value, double duration = 1.0)
{
   originalValue_ = currentValue();
   targetValue_ = value;
   remaining_ = duration;
   duration_ = duration;
   t = 0.0;
}

double currentValue() const {
   return SmoothStep(originalValue_, targetValue_, t); //x*x*(3 - 2*x)
}

void update(double deltaT) {
   remaining_ = fmax(0.0, remaining_ - deltaT);
   t = clamp(0.0, 1.0, 1.0 - remaining_ / duration_)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use SmoothStep and calculate the right input values to make the motion look smooth, or are you open to another method that is similar to SmoothStep in some way?

Comment: @VictorT. I would prefer to use smoothstep, but if there is another function with similar look/feel it would work for my current needs as well (though I would like to have multiple easing functions eventually, so the best answer would be a method how to do that for any easing). I also I dont really need perfect result (=continuous 2nd derivation), good looking transition is what I am after.

Comment: If the new `targetValue_` is always in the same direction as the old one, then your approach (build in the math to select `originalValue_` and `remaining_` so that speed is preserved) seems reasonable. If not, I'd isolate the output by tracking it and its velocity, then accelerate it towards the output of `SmoothStep`.

Comment: @VictorT. can you elaborate? And no, the new input doesnt have to be in same direction. Finding the speed is easy(I hope its correct) if that helps finding the answer - it is first derivative of easing function times times difference between start and endpoint, e.g. for smoothstep it is `(targetValue_-originalValue_) * x * (6 - 6x)`

Comment: I can elaborate on accelerating towards the output of `SmoothStep`, yes. Store two new values, `current` and `velocity`. In `update`, call `SmoothStep` and use a fixed acceleration to adjust `velocity` so that `current` is pushed toward the output value. Return `current` from `currentValue()`.

Comment: To be fair, the code I described above also works if you simply accelerate directly toward `targetValue_`. It just wouldn't be using SmoothStep any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing one important information - [SmoothStep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) is a cubic spline interpolation with endpoints derivative being zero. There is well-known [solution to cubic interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html).
Luckily for case of animation there is no need to solve the linear equation system. Because the D<sub>i+1</sub> is 0 by definition, all that is needed is first derivative D<sub>i</sub> at current `t` which is trivial for fixed order polynomial. Substituting to the equations we get new coeficients:

```
double derivative(double t) const {
   return coeff[0] + t * (2 * coeff[1] + 3 * t * coeff[2]); //b+2cx+3dx*x
}

//in setTargetValue compute new coefficients
double coeff[3];//a = 0 by definition
//note: in real implementation interval length compensation is also needed
coeff[0] = derivative(t);//b 
coeff[1] = 3 - 2 * coeff[0];//c
coeff[2] = -2 + coeff[0];//d
```

and evaluate the SmoothStep `t` mapping as follows

```
double SmoothStepT(double t) const {
   return t * (coeff[0] + t * (coeff[1] + t * coeff[2])); //bx+cx*x+dx*x*x
}

double currentValue() const {
   return Lerp(originalValue_, targetValue_, SmoothStepT(t)); 
}
```

desmos [graph demonstrating smoothness](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pggesspjo6) with two extensions:
[image: animation extension]
*note: coefficient `a` and `x - t` is added to "move" the extended animation to place where the previous one left to demonstrate smoothness.*
*note2: I am not a mathematician, if you see an error in my math, please correct me*