# remove sudden upward & downward jerk from camera

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rpg, navmesh

I have a scene with low poly assets & NavMesh enabled for character navigation. When player climbs the bridge there's a sudden upward jerk in camera. Also, when the player comes down, there's a downward jerk in Camera.

I want the camera movement to be smooth so it appears as if the y-axis of the camera is floating like a drone. Below is my script that I'm using

[image: Picture of Scene]

```
public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour {

float MIN_X = -26.72f;
float MAX_X = 34f;
float MIN_Z = -6.22f;
float MAX_Z = 47.6f;
float MAX_Y = 15f;
float MIN_Y = 0.6f;


public float startYPositionOfCamera;

// The target we are following
public Transform target;
// The distance in the x-z plane to the target
public float distance = 10.0f;
// the height we want the camera to be above the target
public float height = 5.0f;
// How much we 
public float heightDamping = 2f;
public float rotationDamping = 3.0f;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Smooth Follow")]

void Start()
{
    startYPositionOfCamera = transform.position.y;    
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    // Early out if we don't have a target
    if (!target) return;

    // Calculate the current rotation angles
    float wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
    float wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;

    float currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    float currentHeight = transform.position.y;

    // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
    currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    // Damp the height
    currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    // Convert the angle into a rotation
    var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentRotationAngle, 0);

    // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
    // distance meters behind the target
    transform.position = target.position;
    transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

    // Set the height of the camera
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, currentHeight, transform.position.z);

    // Always look at the target
    transform.LookAt(target);

    // Clamp the position of camera so it doesn't go back of mountains
    transform.position = new Vector3(
            Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, MIN_X, MAX_X),
            Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, MIN_Y, MAX_Y),
            Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, MIN_Z, MAX_Z)
        );
}
```

}

Comment: You can have a look at my past question about cubic spline [animation smoothing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139168/smoothly-extend-eased-animation-to-new-target-value) - it is possible to employ it for camera control as well. Would that type of solution satisfy your needs?